# Does Kyros have two legs on this picture?

Tags: one-piece

Is that me or Kyros has his second leg back when sleeping on the first page of chapter 794?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [Aditya](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/55847/50667), there seems to be different versions. The official US release, like several online pages, shows Kyros with only one leg:

[image: english version]

However, Viz released volume 79 on August 2, 2016, over a year after chapter 794 was first released. A possible mistake could have very well been noticed and corrected in the meantime.

I found a scan of the original Tankōbon 79, released on October 3, 2015 in Japan. It also shows the correct picture:

[image: japanese tankoubon version]

Not as likely anymore but given the large popularity of One Piece, eleven weeks might have been sufficient for a correction.

So I went even further back, up to the very origin of this picture. I ordered Weekly Shōnen Jump #2323 and on July 18, 2015, this picture looked like that:

[image: original version]

So it was indeed a mistake!

I discovered a while later that [One Piece Wiki](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/One_Piece_Wiki) lists all mistakes that have been found so far in each Tankōbon as well as the corresponding correction. The one mentioned here can also be found [there](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Volume_79).

Comment: Very nice answer and even better with the link provided! I didn't know about it, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks its a mistake from the site you read One Piece, this is the picture from Viz Digital Colored, The official translation and release.

[image]

It shown Kyros only have one leg.

Comment: It's a good point that I admittedly missed. But why would publishers subsequently ADD a leg? As far as I get it, Viz Digital is the official publisher for the US market. It released Vol. 79 on August 2, 2016. That is over a year after chapter 794 was first released in Weekly Shōnen Jump (week 29, 2015). Plenty of time to fix any obvious bug. Look closely at the picture you posted: the wood plank where the additional foot used to be drawn looks crudely modified. Same holds for the blanket that now looks awkwardly flat.